# In MS Word 2010, with Paragraph marks on, what is the little circle that appears in front of some words or paragraph marks?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm editing in MS Word 2010, and with Paragraph marks on, I see little superscript circles in front of some words and paragraph marks. I don't see a pattern, and they don't seem to be doing any harm. Just curious.

Answer (score 6):

> A degree symbol ° represents a nonbreaking space
>   (Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar), which you can use to prevent words from being
>   separated at the end of a line.
>
> This is useful for keeping dates together (so you don't end up with
>   September
>   5, 2000), as well as initials such as J. P.
>   V. D. Balsdon.
>
> En and em spaces (on the Special Characters tab of the Symbol dialog)
>   are also represented by the degree symbol, but there is extra space to
>   the left of the symbol for an en space ° and extra space both left and
>   right for an em  ° space.

[Article](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/NonPrintChars.htm) contributed by Suzanne S. Barnhill and Dave Rado.